# docker-compose MongoDB Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I`m trying to connect to mongodb in docker container from outside with mongo, but I get the following error.

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-30T14:54:13.950+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

When I bash into the Container everything is fine.
It was working maybe half a year ago but now it won't.
I think it's a problem with docker-compose, but I don't get it.

The versions of the shell and server are the same.
For testing this is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
networks:
  backend:
    external:
      name: my-mongo-cluster

services:

  ## Config Servers
  config01:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27017 --configsvr --replSet configserver --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  config02:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27017 --configsvr --replSet configserver --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  config03:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27017 --configsvr --replSet configserver --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  ## Shards
  shard01a:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27018 --shardsvr --replSet shard01 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  shard01b:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27018 --shardsvr --replSet shard01 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  shard02a:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27019 --shardsvr --replSet shard02 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  shard02b:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27019 --shardsvr --replSet shard02 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  shard03a:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27020 --shardsvr --replSet shard03 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend

  shard03b:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 27020 --shardsvr --replSet shard03 --noprealloc --smallfiles --oplogSize 16 
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend


  ## Router
  router:
    image: mongo
    command: mongos --port 27017 --configdb configserver/config01:27017,config02:27017,config03:27017 
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    networks: 
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - config01
      - config02
      - config03
      - shard01a
      - shard01b
      - shard02a
      - shard02b
      - shard03a
      - shard03b
```

Comment: Nobody with the same issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this same issue
I resolved it by adding following keyword to mongos: **--bind_ip_all**

so
change:

```
mongos --port 27017 --configdb configserver/config01:27017,config02:27017,config03:27017
```

to:

```
 mongos --bind_ip_all --port 27017 --configdb configserver/config01:27017,config02:27017,config03:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. In my case a script was first starting up docker and then connecting to it using mongo.exe.

The solution was to introduce a 3 second sleep before mongo.exe connects and starts executing queries. Another workaround was not binding docker ip to specific local ip and allowing access from all ips. However that was not an option for me.