# sharding mogodb using docker container :docker-compose MongoDB Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, sharding

I am trying sharding mongodbs. I have replicated the config server and also shards.But while connecting using router I get "Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:60001'". I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605575/docker-compose-mongodb-error-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-ism?answertab=active#tab-top) but still getting same error. I am new to mongodb

I am using docker containers for each mongo instance
Here is .yaml file

""""

```
version: '3'

services:

  cfgsvr1:
    container_name: cfgsvr1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 40001:27017
    volumes:
      - cfgsvr1:/data/db

  cfgsvr2:
    container_name: cfgsvr2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 40002:27017
    volumes:
      - cfgsvr2:/data/db

  cfgsvr3:
    container_name: cfgsvr3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 40003:27017
    volumes:
      - cfgsvr3:/data/db

volumes:
  cfgsvr1: {}
  cfgsvr2: {}
  cfgsvr3: {}

version: '3'

services:

  mongos:
    container_name: mongos
    image: mongo
    command: mongos --bind_ip_all --port 27017 --configdb cfgrs/cfgsvr3:27017,cfgsvr2:27017,cfgsvr1:27017
    ports:
      - 60001:27017


version: '3'

services:

  shard1svr1:
    container_name: shard1svr1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50001:27017
    volumes:
      - shard1svr1:/data/db

  shard1svr2:
    container_name: shard1svr2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50002:27017
    volumes:
      - shard1svr2:/data/db

  shard1svr3:
    container_name: shard1svr3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50003:27017
    volumes:
      - shard1svr3:/data/db

volumes:
  shard1svr1: {}
  shard1svr2: {}
  shard1svr3: {}




version: '3'

services:

  shard2svr1:
    container_name: shard2svr1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50004:27017
    volumes:
      - shard2svr1:/data/db

  shard2svr2:
    container_name: shard2svr2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50005:27017
    volumes:
      - shard2svr2:/data/db

  shard2svr3:
    container_name: shard2svr3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard2rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50006:27017
    volumes:
      - shard2svr3:/data/db

volumes:
  shard2svr1: {}
  shard2svr2: {}
  shard2svr3: {}
```

""""
my ubuntu version is 18.04
my dbversion is 3.6.3
my shell version is 3.6.3
logs

```
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:24.527+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cfgsvr3:27017
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:24.527+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cfgsvr1:27017
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:24.536+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set cfgrs
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:25.027+0000 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cfgsvr2:27017
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:25.033+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set cfgrs
mongos    | 2019-12-19T09:14:25.539+0000 W  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set cfgrs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found error as I was replicating **config server** without " configsvr: true,"
and

```
sh.addShard("shard_replica/shard1,shard2,shard3")
sh.addShard("shard_replica2/shard4,shard5,shard6")






version: '2'
services:
  shard1:
    container_name: shard1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 40001:27017
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data1:/data/db
  shard2:
    container_name: shard2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 40002:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data2:/data/db
  shard3:
    container_name: shard3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 40003:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data3:/data/db
  cfg1:
    container_name: cfg1 
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet conf_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 50001:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/config1:/data/db
  cfg2:
    container_name: cfg2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet conf_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 50002:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/config2:/data/db
  cfg3:
    container_name: cfg3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet conf_replica --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 50003:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/config3:/data/db

  shard4:
    container_name: shard4
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica2 --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data4:/data/db

  shard5:
    container_name: shard5
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica2 --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 30002:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data5:/data/db

  shard6:
    container_name: shard6
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard_replica2 --dbpath /data/db --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 30003:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /home/Chinmay/Documents/Chinmay/learn-mongodb/new/data6:/data/db


  mongos:
    container_name: mongos
    image: mongo
    depends_on:
      - cfg1
      - cfg2
      - cfg3
      - shard1
      - shard2
      - shard3
      - shard4
      - shard5
      - shard6

    command: mongos --configdb conf_replica/cfg1:27017,cfg2:27017,cfg3:27017 --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Comment: Had a similar problem. Adding `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` on mongos command solve it.